# Enclose individual elements of a vector in single quotes for processing in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, r, vector

I'm trying to run a query on SQL Server from R. I have a bunch of `custnum` and I would like to connect to SQL Server and get the corresponding data for these `custnum`. I have a vector of `custnum` which is numeric and the corresponding datatype in SQL Server is `varchar`. So I have a requirement to enclose the individual elements of this vector in single quotes so that I can run a query like the following (note that this query is to be run from R using `RODBC` connection):

```
Select Field1, Field2, Field3
from table
where custnum in paste("(", blah, ")")
```

where `blah` looks like:

```
blah <- c(1,2,3)
```

My vector looks like the usual numeric R vector - `c(1,2,3)`.
How do I convert it to look like `c("'1','2','3'")`? Note that this string that I want has all the individual elements enclosed in single quotes (for SQL Server), separated by comma. I tried to use `toString()` which collates all the `custnum` and spits out a single string, but I want each individual element to be enclosed in single quotes, separated by comma.

Any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahh, I think I got it:

```
paste("(",toString(paste("'",blah,"'", sep='')),")", sep='')
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin - this is the complete answer which I realized shortly after I posted the question.

Comment: When I used the result was a string enclosed in quotes, not each element enclosed in quotes. '{"yo", "yo", "yo"} went to 'yo, yo yo', not 'yo', 'yo', 'yo'

Comment: Sorry, I was passing the inputs wrong. This is exactly what I needed and it works as expected! Thanks!